# Adding image in an iOS Launch Screen - Xcode

Tags: xcode, image

This is my Xcode Launch Screen View:
[image]

On the very bottom right I am supposes to see this box to drag the image:

[image]

How Can I show this box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cmd + Shift + L is now the shortcut to see the Library. It’s no longer always visible.

Answer (score 0):

There is a  **+**  button upper right corner to access it.

[image]